# No aparece un icono de Font Awesome. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial ya que estoy iniciando en este mundillo y me ha surgido esto. El icono no aparece

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```
<body>

    <div class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
```

Si alguien sabe la respuesta porfavor dejarlo por las respuestas. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás importando Font Awesome.

1. La solución es importar el script en el `<head>Aqui va el script</head>` de nuestra aplicación

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-10/jx2EXwxxWqCLX/hHth/vu2KY3jCF70dCQB8TSgNjbCVAC/8vai53GfMDrO2Emgwccf2pJqxct9ehpzG+MTw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: Eso si que lo tengo en el codigo. De echo tengo otro icono de busqueda y otro angle double right que me funciona perfectamente.